FreeRTOS MPLAB implementation (WITHOUT MPLAB HARMONY)
Good morning/afternoon
I'm currently programing a PIC32MX795F512L in MPLAB, the problem I'm getting is while trying to implement the FreeRTOS library.
I have downloaded it from its official page, added to the main folder and selected the source directories onto the preprocessing (GCC-preprocessing). But I still get errors trying to compile. I have also included the header files in my main project:
#include "FreeRTOS/Source/include/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MPLAB/PIC32MX/portmacro.h"

[enter image description hereenter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/pBsii5mf.png)

The preferred way here to post the error messages is as text. Copy all the error message then put three back ticks (\``) in a new line, then add a new line paste your error, then again add a new line and put another (````). Visit the help center to see more about how to ask and edit questions.

You image showing include folders isn't likely to help. If your include folders where wrong, you would get errors during compilation when including the headers. But you get linker errors. You need to check the library path entries and the libraries you add.
